# Get row id and input value from mat-table (angular)

Tags: angular, input, angular-material, mat-table

I have a table with several columns and one of them is the input. Under the table I have a button upon which click I would like to update the database, with one click to update age for all users. So for the call, I will need row id and input value for each user. Could anyone please explain how to do it?

TS

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: User[] = [
  { id: 1, country: 'UK', name: 'A', age: 20 },
  { id: 2, country: 'France', name: 'B', age: 21 },
  { id: 3, country: 'Germany', name: 'C', age: 22 }
];

export interface User {
    id: number;
    country: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['country', 'name', 'age'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="country">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Country </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.country}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <div>
          <input type="text" class="age-input" value="{{element.age}}">
        </div>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table> 

  <button mat-raised-button type="submit">
    <i class="material-icons mr-2">save</i>Save
  </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is bind the value of your `input` element via `ngModel` and your `dataSource` will be updated.

```
<input type="text" class="age-input" [(ngModel)]="element.age">
```

> See
>   [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-oocbdw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts),
>   on click of the save button the updated model will be printeg to the
>   console.

Comment: thank you, I am able to get the data now but how to get ONLY Id and Age (so that I can pass those values to the backend). I tried using .map but without success...